# How to handle development for multiple customers of ours using the Postmates API

Tags: postmates

We would like to develop an app which can be used by multiple customers (of ours). Each app will be customized to each customer of ours.

What we are unsure about is how to handle authentication keys and API keys? Do we create one set of these for each of our customers or do we just have one account and all our customers use the one set of API keys. The latter approach makes me nervous because if one customer is banned (for what ever reason) then all my customers will suffer since they all share the same API key.

Any guidance from Postmates development team would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we do not support provisioning multiple API keys for a single account.

I recommend having each client create an API key. This also would allow your customers to use their own payment method, versus a single payment method for every customer.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a process where we can put a 'Connect to Postmates' link on our site (like STRIPE does with STRIPE CONNECT). The result is that the API key is returned back to use after the account is setup so that we can auto store the key in our DB for subsequent calls?

Comment: We don't support that right now, but it's a great idea, and we'll add it to our product backlog.